# Proving Big-Omega Function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to prove that a function is in Ω(^3), however the **constant** *C* is **fixed to 3**.

The function is:

```
() = 3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20
```

In order to prove that  is Ω(^3), we need constants , _0 > 0 such that

```
|()| ≥ C|^3|
```

for every  ≥ _0.

---

When plugging in C = 3, you would get the inequality

```
3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20 ≥ 3^3
```

which would equal

```
−39^2 + 360 + 20 ≥ 0
```

I'm stuck here, because I can't find an *n_0* that satisfies the equation for every  ≥ 0.

---

Also, if c = 2.25 fixed, how do I find the smallest integer that satisfies n_0 ?

Comment: In short: It is not possible for a fixed *C = 3*.

Comment: This question seems a bit odd because it would be unusual to fix some choice of c and then solve for n0. Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

### How to prove it in general

Proving  in Ω(^3) with () = 3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20 is pretty simple.

The exact definition (from Wikipedia) is:
[image: Definition]

---

In words you need to find a constant *c* such that *c * g* will always be smaller than *f* (from a given *n_0*). You are of course allowed to choose this *c* small and the **n_0** big.

We first drop some unnecessary stuff in order to estimate *f*:

- −39^2 is greater than *-n^3* for all *n >= 39*
- 360 is obviously greater than *0*
- *20* is also greater than *0*

Okay, putting that together we receive:

```
f(n) >= 3n^3 - n^3 + 0 + 0
      = 2n^3
```

for *n >= 39*.

We choose *C = 2* (or something smaller), *n_0 = 39* (or something greater) and follow that

```
     C * |g(n)| = 2 * |n^3| <= |2 * n^3| <= |f(n)|
<=>  C * |g(n)| <= |f(n)|
```

for all *n > n_0*. By definition this means  in Ω(^3).

---

### Your specific scenario

For *C = 3* fixed this is obviously not possible since *3 * n^3* is always greater than 3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20 (for some *n_0*). This is due to the second summand −39^2.

Take a look at the plot:

[image: Plot showing both functions]

You see that *3n^3* grows beyond *f*, for all *n >= n_0* with *n_0* at about *9.286*. The exact value is:

```
n >= (2 / 39) * (90 + 8295^(0.5))
```

Here is the query at [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+n+:+3n%5E3+%3E%3D+3n%5E3+-+39n%5E2+%2B+360n+%2B+20).

**But it is possible** for a fixed *C = 2.25* as you can see at [this query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+n+:+2.25n%5E3+%3C%3D+3n%5E3+-+39n%5E2+%2B+360n+%2B+20). It is true for all *n >= 40*.

[image: range for which it is true]